# Finding the other root of the quadratic equation in specific form

Tags: quadratics

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550052/proving-the-second-root-of-a-quadratic-equation) has been solved. However, I notice that both the solutions (including the comment) are **verifying** the fact that $4\alpha^3-3\alpha$ is the other root if $\alpha$ is one.

What if I rephrase the question as:-

If $\alpha$ is a root of the equation$4x^2 + 2x – 1 = 0$, express the other root in the form of 4h + 3k where h should be in terms of $\alpha^3$ and k should be in terms of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta$ the other root. By *Vieta's relations*, $\alpha+\beta=-\dfrac12$.
Now rewrite the equation satisfied by $\alpha$  as
$$-\frac12=-2\alpha^2-\alpha,\enspace\text{so that}\quad\beta=-2\alpha^2-2\alpha.$$
Also , multiplying the equation by $\alpha$, you obtain $\;4\alpha^3+2\alpha^2-\alpha=0$, i.e. $\;-2\alpha^2=4\alpha^3-\alpha$. Replace $-2\alpha^2$ in the expression of $\beta$:
$$\beta=-2\alpha^2-2\alpha=4\alpha^3-3\alpha.$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\alpha$ is a root of $ax^2+bx+c$, then

$$\alpha^2+\tfrac ba \alpha+\tfrac ca=0$$

Thus,

\begin{align}
\alpha^3&=\alpha\cdot\alpha^2\\
&=\alpha\cdot(-\tfrac ba \alpha - \tfrac ca)\\
&=-\tfrac ba \alpha^2 - \tfrac ca\alpha\\
&=-\tfrac ba\cdot(-\tfrac ba \alpha - \tfrac ca) - \tfrac ca\alpha\\
&=\tfrac {b^2}{a^2}\alpha + \tfrac {bc}{a^2} - \tfrac ca\alpha\\
&=\tfrac {b^2-ac}{a^2}\alpha + \tfrac {bc}{a^2}
\end{align}

So we can find the other root $\beta=-\frac ba-\alpha$ by seeing
$$\frac ba=\frac{a}{c}\left(\alpha^3-\tfrac {b^2-ac}{a^2}\alpha\right)$$

and so
$$\beta=-\frac{a}{c}\left(\alpha^3-\tfrac {b^2-ac}{a^2}\alpha\right)-\alpha$$
which in the requested form is
$$\beta=\tfrac {ab^2-2a^2c}{a^2c}\alpha-\tfrac ac\alpha^3$$

Comment: Direct substitution of a = 4, b = 2, c = -1 into your last result does not give the required target.

Comment: I missed a minus sign halfway. It's fixed now, thanks