# If a is one of the root of the equation 4x^2+2x-1=0. Then find the other root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If a is one of the root of the equation 4x^2+2x-1=0. Then find the other root 
[image]

MY WORK:
[image]

I tried using the sum and product of rules formula to find b in terms of a but I didnt get the answer according to the options given.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550052/proving-the-second-root-of-a-quadratic-equation

Answer (score 0):

It's trivially $4a^3 - 3a$$~~~~~$